# "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." on IIS 7.5 with WinServer 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I have just uploaded my ASP.NET MVC 4 website through Visual Studio 2012 (FTP method). I login to my Windows Server and can see the files have been uploaded.

I've checked all bindings ... etc. But when I try and visit the website in my browser, all I get is this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have checked [this thread](http://bit.ly/1dzrmUw), and tried everything that is mentioned there, but nothing worked.

Comment: Is the default document setup in IIS for your application?  Also, to possibly debug, enable directory browsing so you can see where it first takes you.

Comment: I have other websites on the server, and I didn't have to do anything related to default document set-up for them. In any case, I better check, can you please provide instructions on how I'd do that, also how to enable directory browsing? Thanks

Comment: To check the default document, open IIS, click on your website, and under the IIS menu, there is a "Default Document" icon.  Double click it, then on the right click "Add..." Add whatever your default document is (i.e. default.aspx).
For Directory Browsing, its the icon next to the default document when you click on your site.  Click on that icon and on the right you should see an "enable" link.  Click it directory browsing will be enabled.